# Ruby on rails 7 destroy not showing alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

When I click on delete, alert not show and go to this path `course_path`, but don't delete the course.

```
def destroy
    authorize @course
    @course.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to courses_url, notice: "Course was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

```
before_action :set_course, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
```

The view:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', course, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'
```

the `_messages.htm.haml` file is:

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  - if msg.is_a?(String)
    %div{:class => "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'}", :rol => "alert"}
      %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} ✘ 
      = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
```

how to fix this?
Could `jQuery` be a problem?

Comment: You could share the logs of your rails server, this would help others debug

Comment: `data-method="delete"` and `data-confirm` are both handled by Rails UJS. It was rewritten to remove the jQuery dependency way back in the Rails 5 and is replaced as a default by Turbo in Rails 7. Rails 7 has a brand new assets pipeline as well so if you're upgrading you may have broken your existing assets. I have a feeling we are gonna see a lot of this generally unanswerable question in the next few months.

Comment: If you want to continue using Rails UJS you need to ensure its actually included in your page and that you don't have any script errors that are preventing it from working. If you want to bite the bullet there is a guide for upgrading to [Turbo](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/UPGRADING.md).

Answer (score 0):

In rails 7, it would be:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', course, data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'
```